# How to divide an geographic area into uniform rectangular grid or cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, latitude-longitude, geo

I have many earthquake data point in a two dimensional plan(Latitude and longitude). I have to divide entire area into a rectangular grid/cell/box and also access the falling data point of a respective cell in MATLAB.

I mean to say divide entire region into sub-regions.

Can you explain with MATLAB Code

Comment: right back at you: Can you explain with MATLAB Code

Comment: X=70:1:100; % X is the range of 
 %Y=linspace( min_Lat,max_long,100);
 Y=20:1:40;
 LL=length(X)*length(Y);
 for i=1:N
     for j=1:30
         for k=1:20
     if(X(j)<=catalog(i,3)<X(j+1) && Y(k)<=catalog(i,2)<Y(k+1)) 
         Z2=catalog(i,:); 
     end
         end
     end

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without major effort, is to subdivide into spherical rectangles, by just using a latitudinalSpan, and longitudinalSpan.

Then just have a 2d-array, and you calculate the cell index by 
i = latitude / latitudeSpan
j = longitude / longitudeSpan

The cells are not anymore of equals width measured in meters, when you go north or south from equator. But you should live with that limitation.